# Continually updating task pane

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook Add-in through Visual Studio with C# and I am attempting to continually update a variable on a task pane. I would like the user to be able to open up the task pane, and watch the variable increment in real-time. Here's a basic example of what I am working on:

```
togglebutton1_click(object sender, EventhandlerArgs e){
    value += 1;

    taskPane.label.text = "" + value;
}
```

I am trying to update the task pane until a given time frame has ended. I tried to update the label in the timer handler, but I was not able to update it as it was created in a different thread. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Controls in Windows Forms are bound to a specific thread and are not thread safe. Therefore, if you are calling a control's method from a different thread, you must use one of the control's invoke methods to marshal the call to the proper thread.

Basically, you need to use the [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) method and the [InvokeRequired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the Control class. This property can be used to determine if you must call an invoke method, which can be useful if you do not know what thread owns a control.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunction));
     myThread.Start();
  }
  private void ThreadFunction()
  {
     MyThreadClass myThreadClassObject  = new MyThreadClass(this);
     myThreadClassObject.Run();
  }


  // The following code assumes a 'ListBox' and a 'Button' control are added to a form, 
  // containing a delegate which encapsulates a method that adds items to the listbox.

 public class MyThreadClass
 {
    MyFormControl myFormControl1;
    public MyThreadClass(MyFormControl myForm)
    {
       myFormControl1 = myForm;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
       // Execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns
       // 'myFormControl1' control's underlying window handle.
       myFormControl1.Invoke(myFormControl1.myDelegate);
    }
 }
```

An even better solution is to use the SynchronizationContext returned by [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than a control for cross-thread marshaling.